# ASP.NET MVC 5: How to disable custom error page from 3rd party library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, custom-error-pages

I have an old asp.net mvc 5 website (.NET 4.5) that is built on a closed-source 3rd party library. In the web.config of my website, I tried to turn on custom errors:

```
<customErrors mode="On" />
```

Instead of my error page showing up, a custom error page from the library showed up. Browsing the library with a reflector, I found a class that looks like this:

```
  [GeneratedCode("RazorGenerator", "2.0.0.0")]
  [PageVirtualPath("~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml")]
  public class Error : WebViewPage<HandleErrorInfo>
  {
    public override void Execute()
    {
      ...
    }
  }
```

The execute method contains HTML for the page content.

Is this class alone enough to override the custom error behavior, or is there some more configuration hiding elsewhere?

Is there some way I could programatically override the custom error behavior with my own error?

Answer (score 0):

You can return your error page like below from your controller method;

```
 return Redirect("/error");
```

Comment: I'm hoping to show the error page for uncaught errors, such as when the wrong parameters are provided to an action.